# Windows azure VM not giving the US site

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, azure

I have created a VM in Windows Azure. If I browser google.com from that VM it is redirecting me to google.es. The VM created in West US region.

And I tried to change the DNS server in ipv4 setting but this doesn't solve my problem. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Could you please clarify why the version of Google you're getting is important?  What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm creating a monitoring tool. this tool will make a http call to the webpage and will download the page view source. And then we can search for a specific string in that page to make sure the webpage is up and running. I added google.com as my webpage and 'I'm feeling lucky' as my text to search, and tool failed to find it. then when I tried to browse google.com from browser I saw it redirected to google.es and in this page we don't have 'I'm feeling lucky'.

Comment: Azure now uses IP Addresses from other countries in the US, because they ran out of US IPs (v4)

Comment: Azure did not "run out of" USA IPv4s. Different tools use different ways to get locate the IP. For example, Google geolocates my Norwegian IP as being in Indonesia and my Nevada IP as being in Texas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass any country-specific redirections by using `http://www.google.com/ncr` instead of `http://www.google.com`.  ("NCR" stands for "no country redirect.")  Hopefully, that will solve your problem.